# Graphing a function.. the definition contains min, max, gcd.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, gcd-and-lcm, math-software

Let $x=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$.

Graph the function;

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\min(p,q)+1}{\max(p,q)+1} & \text{if }\text{GCD}(p,q)=1 \\ 
 & \\ 
0 & \text{if }\text{GCD}(p,q)\neq1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Graphing the function by hand is quite easy to understand, and quite difficult to plot. Unfortunately I do not know any graphing website or software where we can define a function as mentioned. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is really difficult to plot this function, since it is a very particular and unusual case. However, I have a tip for you.
You can generate your own script for plotting it using programming methods.
Bellow is an idea of how to build your algorithm.

- define $p=1$ and $q=1$
- from $i=1$ to $N_1$ do
- from $j=1$ to $N_2$ do
- $p=p+1$
- $q=q+1$
- define $F=\dfrac{\text{min}(p,q)+1}{\text{max}(p,q)+1}$
- find common divisors of p and q (this requires a factorization algorithm)
- put their common divisors in decreasing order
- if the highest common divisor is one, write in the external file $\left(\dfrac{p}{q}, F\right)$
- else, write in the external file $\left(\dfrac{p}{q}, 0\right)$

You can choose the $N_1$ and $N_2$ values, but remember the bigger $N_1$ and $N_2$ the higher your program will take to factorize p and q.
After that, you can use any simple program to plot your external file.

Comment: If you want to add a pseudocode, the identation will help a lot (like python). So try to make 4 spaces in every new line for identation

Comment: @LuisFelipe thank you so much. I am a new user here, still learning. Your comment will be of great help for me.

Comment: also, you can select a section and press `ALT`+`K`